# PHP and composer command don't work without admin CMD

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I have problem with my PHP and composer. I have set environment variables:
[image]

But whenever I call `php` or `composer` I get an error:
[image]

It's weird, because when I start cmd as an admin it works. But I want it to work always, because its much easier to write `cmd` to navigation path which opens the command line in exact path I use and don't need to write `cd` commands every time I need something.

Comment: Some of my thoughts are: Have you tried to relogin into your account? Is the path and files readyble and executable by your user? Is this a company domain with a non domain administrator account?

Comment: I haven't tried re-login account, but I set path for PHP like a week ago and PC was turned off several times so I guess this will not help. I checked these paths and bot are readable for me. It's my personal computer so I'm the admin account.

Comment: Can you verify that `echo %PATH%` contains your composer?

Comment: It's there `...;E:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Patrik\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`. It printed me it twice since I have included these paths in the user PATH too.

Comment: Ok. Does a composer.exe or composer.bat exists in those two paths? I havent tried installing composer on windows yet so i dont know.

Comment: In the ProgramData there files like `composer`, `composer.bat`, `composer.phar`. I will try to restart PC if it makes change, but still don't know what's wrong with `php` command (I'm running XAMPP).

Comment: Seems like it fixed it. Still don't know why or how, because I have PHP for long time. We can close this Q.

Comment: good to hear it is working!

Comment: Me too :-) Thanks for helping to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing composer with the Windows GUI? If I remember correctly, it sets up your path variables itself.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

You could try adding the same path to your user path variables too, in the first box. I guess you're restarting your CMD window?

Comment: Yes I used an installer. I tried tu put same path to user PATH, but no help. And yes, I'm restarting my CMD everytime I make change.

Comment: So you're saying if you run CMD as an admin, `composer` is available, but not ran as an admin, it's not? I just checked my path variables, and I have none in my user variables, but `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` in my system path variable.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it is already working (both composer and php), I had to restart PC, i thought that restart CMD is enough.

Comment: @debute That's good news. And slightly odd that you needed to restart.

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm glad it helped. Also thanks for helping.